# How to accept and automatically merge a pull request on github

Tags: git, pull-request

There is a pull request on our github repo that I would like to fully accept. It is not obvious how (if even possible) to do this directly on the github gui.

What is the most reliable way to do this - preferably without requiring to perform another local git clone.

Comment: If the PR merges without conflicts, just click the "Merge pull request" button.

Comment: @SvenMarnach  I do not see such a button (or yes I would have clicked it ;) ).  Now the thing is, I am a committer. So .. is there a chance that "merge" is a different permission (that I might not have) ?

Comment: It of course requires write permission to the repository, but nothing special as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I looked that up - I am a collaborator and they should have merge permission. This is frustrating.

Comment: Are you logged in with the right account?

Comment: @SvenMarnach  Ohhh.. I do have two accounts: and it is showing the other one..  If you want some points then feel free to make this an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the GitHub web interface : https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/

Comment: as noted in the (updated) OP there is no merge button available to me. I am a project collaborator so it does not make sense.

Comment: The issue is I have two accounts and for some reason the wrong one got logged on.